# What do the numbers in stacktrace.js correlate to?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, stack-trace

I'm using stacktrace.js, and it returns several lines that include the URL followed by two numbers separated by colons. For example:

```
http://url.com/myscript.js:80:34
```

What does the 80 and the 34, in this example, correlate to? I can't find documentation on this script's use of the numbers.

Comment: Deduplicator what's up with removing the stacktrace.js tag on all questions? I'm monitoring that tag in order to support my library. It's purpose is no different that of the angularjs and similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line 80
character 34

The numbers are unrelated to any numbers in your script.

Comment: For my education sake, what line numbers do they relate to?

Comment: Line 80 would refer to line 80 of that script.  If you were to open the script in a text editor and press the down arrow key 80 times, and the right arrow key 34 times, then it should put your cursor at the point stacktrace is referencing.

Comment: Oh, right; I miss-understood by what you meant by "unrelated." The line numbers appear to be incorrect when I intentionally introduce an error; presumably because I'm using requirejs to combine scripts?

Comment: The line numbers will apply to the resulting, combined file.